# Simple 301 redirect/rewrite on IIS 7 not working

Tags: iis, web-config, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to setup a simple 301 permanent redirect on an IIS 7 server for a site that's run on DotNetNuke 5.6.3 Community Edition.

I was able to setup a rule in the web.config to rewrite non-www to www, and that works just fine.  But, when trying to redirect the homepage to the TLD, nothing happens.  I've tried tons of examples both here on stackoverflow and other sites, but nothing seems to work.  I've also tried changing the URLS in this rule to different ones, just to make sure there wasn't something strange going on with the CMS.

Here's one version of the rule that I've tried using (but there are probably a half dozen other iterations I've tried to get this to work):

```
<rule name="301 permanent redirect" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="http://www.domain.com/Home.aspx" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

What else should I try to get this to work?